# Delayed video overlay using FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, video-editing

I want to overlay one video onto another, but with a delayed appearance. I have:

- `source1.mp4` which is of duration 20 sec.
- `source2.mp4` which is of duration 5 sec.

I want to create a final output in which `source2.mp4` overlaps `source1.mp4` from 00:00:07 to 00:00:12. How can I achieve this?

I have tried the following commands, but none of these serve what I want:

```
ffmpeg -i source1.mp4 -itsoffset 7 -i source2.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -c copy -y output.mp4

ffmpeg -itsoffset 7 -i source2.mp4 -i source1.mp4 -filter_complex 'overlay=0:0' output.mp4

ffmpeg -i source1.mp4 -i source2.mp4 -filter_complex "overlay" -strict -2 output.mp4
```

Comment: I asked this on both sites because it was confusing whether or not it is a programming related question. However I have still not received any answer on either site for this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To do this, you need the latest FFmpeg version (2.2)**. So you should run a command like

```
ffmpeg -i sample1.mp4 -i sample2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+7/TB[v1];[v0][v1]overlay=eof_action=pass[out1]" -map [out1]  /tmp/final.mp4
```

The trick is to set PTS for the second video to +7 seconds (PTS-STARTPTS+7/TB) and then just overlay the two streams.

Comment: When I try this approach, both videos end up being delayed, holding on the start frame until 7 seconds go by. Shouldn't this only have such an effect on the 2nd video input, and not both video inputs?