# ffmpeg - add multiple videos in panes, one master track, give offset start times how?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing, tiles

In these days of COVID, our choir director is recording a video which is the accompaniment, and then each choir member (at home) is listening to the accompaniment in headphones, singing along, and recording their voice and lovely face as a video. I now want to take all these disparate videos and combine them into one video with all the members in small panes, Brady Bunch style. And of course, each choir member has different hardware so the audio levels are all different and need to be normalized. And of course, one person took the video sideways (portrait instead of landscape) so their video has to be cropped before adding it in.

In addition, I need to define the director's video as the "master" stream. So let's say the director has 3 seconds of nonsense at the beginning of her video that doesn't need to be there. I want to start the final video immediately after that nonsense. Then, if choir member #1 started her video 0.4 seconds after the director, I want to discard the first 2.6 seconds of her video. If choir member #2 completely disregarded the instructions and started his video 4.3 seconds after the director, then I need his pane to just be blank for 1.3 seconds in the final video.

And finally, if some of the videos need cropping so they aren't the right shape, I get this lovely green color filling in the blank spots. Is there a way to define that background color, or even have some kind of background image where pieces of it only show up where video streams aren't?

I had asked a [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1595428/ffmpeg-add-multiple-videos-in-panes-give-offset-start-times-how) and am now using this command line:

```
ffmpeg -y -i "Director.MOV"
  -itsoffset 5 -i "Member1.MOV"
  -itsoffset 10 -i "Member2.mp4"
  -filter_complex "
  nullsrc=size=1920x1080 [base];
  [0:v] scale=960x540 [clip0];
  [0:a]volume=1[aud0];
  [1:v] crop=1080:1000:0:920,scale=583x540 [clip1];
  [1:a]volume=2,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud1];
  [2:v] scale=960x540 [clip2];
  [2:a]volume=1.1,aresample=async=1:first_pts=0[aud2];
  [base][clip0] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=0 [tmp0];
  [tmp0][clip1] overlay=shortest=1:x=1148:y=0:enable='gt(t\,5)' [tmp1];
  [tmp1][clip2] overlay=shortest=1:x=0:y=540:enable='gt(t\,10) [tmp2];
  [aud0][aud1][aud2]amix=inputs=3[a]
" -map "[tmp2]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 output.mkv"
```

but this results in the first person's face appearing on screen for a few seconds all by herself, and then the other members joining in at random times, and finally the director.  I want a nice "clean start" please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say the offset added to the Director's video is X seconds. And let's say the nonsense at the front of her video is Y seconds. Then, you would add `-ss X+Y` (with the computed value substituted) after all the inputs.

Replace `nullsrc` with `color`. For YUV format frames, nullsrc translates to a darkish green canvas. `color` defaults to black color.